# Front Panel Not Working - ALC 4080 - Archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I built a system with MSI Z690 MAG Tomahawk DDR4. It has ALC4080 codec. I found similar problems on google.

Output of `aplay -L`

```
    null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pipewire
    PipeWire Sound Server
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
speex
    Plugin using Speex DSP (resample, agc, denoise, echo, dereverb)
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=2
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=4
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=5
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 5
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=6
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 6
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=7
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 7
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=8
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 8
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=9
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 9
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=10
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 10
    HDMI Audio Output
usbstream:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH
    USB Stream Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=0
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=1
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=2
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=4
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 4
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=5
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 5
    HDMI Audio Output
usbstream:CARD=HDMI
    HDA ATI HDMI
    USB Stream Output
default:CARD=Audio
    USB Audio, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=Audio
    USB Audio, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    USB Audio, USB Audio
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    USB Audio, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    USB Audio, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    USB Audio, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    USB Audio, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    USB Audio, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    USB Audio, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    USB Audio, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
iec958:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
    USB Audio, USB Audio #1
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
usbstream:CARD=Audio
    USB Audio
    USB Stream Output
```

I have a speaker connected to the rear audio panel and everythink works fine. But when I plug a headphone to the front panel, speakers keep working and no audio from headphones. I made some research found out that front panel actually works using a `aplay` command.

I tested with this command below.

`aplay -D plughw:Audio,1 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Left.wav`

If I use the command above on the terminal I can have a sound with my headphones plugged in to the front panel.

Anyone know how to solve this issue ?
Note: OS: Arch Linux

Comment: Same here, same mobo (just DDR5 version), aplay also works but no sound on headphones in PulseAudio. Any luck getting this working?

Comment: Found your post in Arch forum: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=272523

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, I didn't see your question before. I totally forgot about the question that I shared in this forum.

Comment: I think I finally found the underlying issue and solution: https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-ucm-conf/issues/189